# Deployment of Django App Through AWS Elastic Beanstalk Breaks CSS Paths

Tags: css, django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have just finished deploying my first simple Django 1.8.6 (in case it matters) app to AWS through Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything seems to be working; however, the styles are not loading.

Here is the code of the template:

```
{% load blog_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
     <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="content">
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
     </div>
     <div id="sidebar">
       <h2>My blog!</h2>
       <p>This is my blog. I have written {% total_posts %} posts so far.</p>
       <h3>Latest posts</h3>
       {% show_latest_posts 3 %}
     </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

And here is the source code of the page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Blog !!!</title>
     <link href="/static/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="content"> ...
```

If I click on the link "/static/css/blog.css" on the local machine, the CSS file opens; however, on the Beanstalk it cannot be found.

I suspect that this has to do with some configs. Any idea where I can look to fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is the .ebextensions/django.config file

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: django_by_example_blog/wsgi.py
    StaticFiles: /static/=static/
```

Comment: Have you read https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#static-files?

Comment: No. I followed another tutorial. I am going to try adding that command.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my config file. According to the tutorial above, it should work or am I missing something?

Comment: Another thing I realized is that I have an app within my project. It is the CSS file from that app's `static` directory that is not loading. Is that a good idea to point `STATIC_ROOT` to it? How can I make sure that apps' static files are served properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AMI 2, then can use this

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: mysite.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```